# Getting the form values as an array in razor asp.net

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a form with values

```
           Price  <input type="text" name="items[price]" value="" /> <br />
       Condition  <input type="text" name="items[condition]" value="" /> <br />
           Brand  <input type="text" name="items[brand]" value="" /> <br />
```

I want to send this to database

```
    string[] allitems = Request.Form["items"];
    var db2x = Database.Open("mystring");

    foreach (var item in allitems)
    {
       var insertCommand2x = "INSERT INTO Classifieds_attr_value (AttrId,CarBikeId,AttrVal) VALUES(@0,@1,@2)";
       db2x.Execute(insertCommand2x, AttrId, CarBikeId, AttrVal);

   }
```

This is not working pls help

Comment: ok after changing name to itam i can get values but is there a way to get related id in the foreach output ? Any help will be greatly appreceated. Thanks Price <input type="text" id="1" name="items" value="" /> <br /> Condition <input type="text" id="2" name="items" value="" /> <br /> Brand <input type="text" id="3" name="items" value="" /> <br /> string[] items = Request.Form.GetValues("items"); foreach(var ax in items){ Response.Write("<br/>" + ax + "-" +Request['id']); }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have to use `items` value for all `input` and read values via `Request.Form.GetValues("items")` method.

```
Price      <input type="text" name="items" value="" /> <br />
Condition  <input type="text" name="items" value="" /> <br />
Brand      <input type="text" name="items" value="" /> <br />
```

and read values,

```
string []items=Request.Form.GetValues("items");
if(items!=null){
   //read
}
```

Or choose different value for *name* attributes.

```
Price      <input type="text" name="price" value="" /> <br />
Condition  <input type="text" name="condition" value="" /> <br />
Brand      <input type="text" name="brand" value="" /> <br />
```

and read key-value,

```
string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
if (keys!= null)
 {
  foreach (var key in keys)
   {
   Response.Write("<br/>" + key + " " + Request.Form[key]);
   }
 }
```

Comment: when i do string[] allitems = Request.Form.GetValues("items"); i get the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: On first request it will be null so verify the reference before you read array elements.